# Update NPM package without dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 2 repositories, one is an app and the other is UI components used in the app (a private bitbucket repo). When I want to update the UI-kit in the app I run `npm update ui-kit` from the app directory which updates the UI-kit but also pulls all of its dependencies which I don't want, as it takes much time and I just want to pull the changes I made in the UI-kit repo.

So how can I update the package without its subdependencies?

Comment: When you update your module, `npm` need to check all dependencies and updates or installs missing (you can change dependency version or add a new one for example). The loaded module, `npm` adds to cache, so when in the next time you install this module with the same version, `npm` loads it from cache, not from repository.

Comment: So i'm asking for a way to tell npm that there's no need to check for anything, just pull one repo.

Comment: I am looking for a feature like that too and I am really wondering why nobody knows an answer..